# how to determine month from year and week number?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I want to get the month name from the week number and year number:

```
date

Week    Year  
  52    2018
  20    2017
  47    2016
```

Comment: What day of the week though? In many cases a week will span 2 months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can `paste` Week day , week number and year together to convert it into Date and then use `format` to get the month name. Read `?strptime` for formatting options

```
format(as.Date(paste(1, df$Week, df$Year), "%u %U %Y"), "%B")
#[1] "December" "May"      "November"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Week = c(52L, 20L, 47L), Year = 2018:2016), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```